# Download a list of specific files from Azure Blob

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I've got an issue with the files download from Azure Blob container. This is not that trivial as it may seem. I saw many examples of how you can download one file, but there's a problem if you need to download a bulk of them.

Issue definition:

- I have an Azure Blob container that has ~30k files in it
- At the same time, I've got a list of exact file names locally (around 300 files) that I want to download from that Azure Blob container (i.e., I need to download a whole bunch of files selectively, by their names)

I know that all these files exist in the given blob. So, I need a way to iterate over the list of the files and download them from the blob.

What I tried:

- I tried 'azcopy copy' command. It works alright if you need to copy one or several files from the blob to your local disk, but there's no way you can pass a huge list of files as a parameter to download those
- Tried to search for PowerShell examples that can do the same, but no luck

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Please try something like the following. It makes use of [`Get-AzStorageBlobContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstorageblobcontent?view=azps-6.4.0) Cmdlet.

The idea is to have an array of blobs you wish to download and then loop over that array and call this Cmdlet for each item.

```
$accountName = "account-name"
$accountKey = "account-key"
$containerName = "container-name"
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountName -StorageAccountKey $accountKey
$destination = "C:\temp"

$blobNames = @("blob1.txt", "blob2.txt", "blob3.txt", "blob4.txt")

For ($i=0; $i -lt $blobNames.Length; $i++) {
    $blob = $blobNames[$i]
    Write-Host "Downloading $blob. Please wait."
    Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Blob $blob -Container $containerName -Destination $destination -Context $context -Verbose
}
```

Comment: This may work. However, I do not want to specify all 300+ file names and write them into the $blobNames variable. Given I've got a "list.txt" file that have all those files listed (separated by a semicolon), how do I read from that file. Basically, I want to read filenames from the text file one by one and get them downloaded.

Comment: I think if you search for reading a text file in PowerShell, you’ll find some ways to accomplish this.

Comment: I'm not a huge expert in PS, but thanks...

Comment: Ok, this worked:
$blobNames = Get-Content $destination\list.txt
Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

```
$accountName = "account-name"
$accountKey = "account-key"
$containerName = "container-name"
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountName -StorageAccountKey $accountKey
$destination = "C:\temp"

$blobNames = Get-Content $destination\list.txt

For ($i=0; $i -lt $blobNames.Length; $i++) {
    $blob = $blobNames[$i]
    Write-Host "Downloading $blob. Please wait."
    Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Blob $blob -Container $containerName -Destination $destination -Context $context -Verbose
}
```

It'll work like a charm, given that the text file that holds a list of file names for the blobs you need to download is located in the '$destination' directory (could be any directory on your PC, though).
p.s., the files just need to be listed as one column (separated by a caret return, i.e., "\n" at the end of each file name).
Thanks @Gaurav Mantri for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "Azure Storage Explorer" soft ?
I was able to download a whole folder from a blob storage thanks to it.

If data in the blob container is in a folder just right click on the folder > Download.

If the files are directly at the root of the container (not stored in a subfolder) you'll have to select all files with the "Select All > Select all files in cache" option then click on "Download".

Comment: OP does not want to download entire folder but a selected list of blobs from the container.

Comment: Then that solution should also work as Azure Storage Explorer enables you to search by filename (or other more complex filters).

Comment: If I am not mistaken, Storage Explorer does not allow you to search by blob name. It allows "prefix" based search but that's completely different. Also the source container has 30000 blobs. Storage Explorer will not search the entire container.

Comment: You're right, it is different. But what does it change if you have to search 300 files one by one by their names ? If he does it programmatically, he does have to declare an array with 300 string in it? If there's no naming convention on the 30k files, then he has to do it one by one.

Comment: OP mentioned that the list of blobs that needs to be downloaded is already available.

Comment: I can have a list of word written on a piece of paper, that doesn't mean it's ready to be used in a program. I'm not here to debate, just tryin to help. Have a good day, sir !

Comment: Azure Storage Explorer doesn't do what I need. It's good for separate file downloads, or getting them by a mask/regex... My case is different. We store the filenames in a database and I need to download the blobs specific for certain customers. We have identified a list of blobs (around 300, as I mentioned) and now I need to get them downloaded.